# Unable to provide random parameter with mlogit

Tags: r, mixed-model, multinomial-distribution

I'm having trouble with rpar argument in the mlogit function (package mlogit).

My dataset looks like this:

```
> head(scan.s)
   year id.scan day weather sealvl wave lact repro     nb.gr       HS nb.pv pup act
1 2011       1   4       2   0.30    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.600000     3   0   R
2 2011       1   4       2   0.30    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.600000     3   0   R
3 2011       1   4       2   0.30    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.600000     3   1   R
4 2011       2   4       2   0.35    3    1     0 0.6666667 8.100000     2   0   R
5 2011       2   4       2   0.35    3    1     0 0.6666667 8.100000     2   1   R
6 2011       3   4       2   0.40    3    1     0 0.6666667 8.633333     2   0   R

> str(scan.s)
'data.frame':   10140 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ year   : int  2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 ...
 $ id.scan: Factor w/ 280 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 ...
 $ day    : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ weather: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ sealvl : num  0.3 0.3 0.3 0.35 0.35 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 ...
 $ wave   : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ lact   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ repro  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nb.gr  : num  0.667 0.667 0.667 0.667 0.667 ...
 $ HS     : num  7.6 7.6 7.6 8.1 8.1 ...
 $ nb.pv  : int  3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ pup    : int  0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ act    : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","C","D","G",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
```

Then I used mlogit.data to transform my dataset in long shape:

```
> scan.l<- mlogit.data(scan, varying = NULL, choice = "act", shape = "wide")
```

There is no variable varying across choices.

```
    year id.scan day weather sealvl wave lact repro     nb.gr  HS nb.pv pup   act chid alt
1.A 2011       1   4       2    0.3    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.6     3   0 FALSE    1   A
1.C 2011       1   4       2    0.3    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.6     3   0 FALSE    1   C
1.D 2011       1   4       2    0.3    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.6     3   0 FALSE    1   D
1.G 2011       1   4       2    0.3    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.6     3   0 FALSE    1   G
1.R 2011       1   4       2    0.3    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.6     3   0  TRUE    1   R
2.A 2011       1   4       2    0.3    3    1     0 0.6666667 7.6     3   0 FALSE    2   A

> str(scan.l)
Classes ‘mlogit.data’ and 'data.frame': 50700 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ year   : int  2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 ...
 $ id.scan: Factor w/ 280 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day    : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ weather: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ sealvl : num  0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 ...
 $ wave   : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ lact   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ repro  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nb.gr  : num  0.667 0.667 0.667 0.667 0.667 ...
 $ HS     : num  7.6 7.6 7.6 7.6 7.6 7.6 7.6 7.6 7.6 7.6 ...
 $ nb.pv  : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ pup    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ act    : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ chid   : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ alt    : chr  "A" "C" "D" "G" ...
 - attr(*, "index")='data.frame': 50700 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ chid: Factor w/ 10140 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ alt : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","C","D","G",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 - attr(*, "choice")= chr "act"
```

Then I ran the model:

```
mod1 <- mlogit(act ~ 1| nb.gr+nb.pv+sealvl+lact+repro+HS+day+id.scan,data = na.omit(scan.l), rpar=id.scan, format="long", reflevel="R", R=100, halton=NA, print.level=0)
```

The random parameter here is a factor and I am supposed to specify a distribution for rpar but is it relevant for a factor? (I tried to provide a distribution without any change).

And then I get this:

```
Error in coef(eval(callst, parent.frame())) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function'coef' : Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular
```

There is a way to use "HS" and "day" instead, both numerical. But then I get another error:

```
Error in names (sup.coef) <- names.sup.coef: Attribute 'names' [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

traceback() did not provide any insight about what happened.

I searched for explanations with those errors and found that there could be a problem between one outcome and the random effect so I tried to subset my dataset with every combination of 3 outcomes with the same result. I found nothing relevant about the second error. Maybe it has something to do with the transformation with mlogit.data. I checked the dataset provided with the mlogit package and could not figure out what I did different.

I would be grateful if someone could explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is because you are including the id.scan variable in the list of covariates. The error where `coef()` is a derivative error because the model is failing to fit correctly -- that's the second error on that same line relating to the system is exactly singular. 
You are confusing the rpar in this specificiation with a "grouping" variable in mixed modelling generally. rpar specifies which covariate is responding to the grouping variable. You specify the grouping variable using the argument `id.var = scan.id` in the call to `mlogit.data()`.

You cannot fit a random parameter model using `mlogit()` for the formula you are specifying. The covariates mentioned in rpar must be alternative specific covariates -- you have to read the vignette very carefully to see that! The example provided by @John Jackson has only the alternative specific covariates (before the `|`) in the rpar statement. I bet if you try:

```
mod1 <- mlogit(act ~ 1 | nb.gr+nb.pv+sealvl+lact+repro+HS+day,data = na.omit(scan.l),  reflevel="R")
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error message when I tried to include a random coefficient on a person specific variable, in this case the intercept, with a wide dataset.  The solution appears to be to:

1. convert the data to the long form;
2. create alternative specific intercepts by interacting a variable equal to one for all observations with each category in the alt variable;
3. estimate a model with these new variables in the list for alternative specific variables and any other person specific variables -1 after the | line;
4. specify each of the alternative specific constant terms in the npar expression.

For the Fishing example, the long data are in fish and the mlogit command is:

```
out<mlogit(mode~oneboat+onecharter+onepier|income-1, fish, 
           rpar=c(oneboat="n",onecharter="n",onepier="n"), R=100, halton=NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by specifying the `rpar` arguments exactly as they appear when you run the regular`mlogit()` command.  So for your example:

```
rpar = list("A:scan.id"="n", "C:scan.id"="n", ...)
```

where they named list must be quoted because of the "`:`" (I think, it may just be for "`(`", but it works with quotes either way).  This is explained in footnote 20 p. 24 of Viton, PA. "Discrete-Choice Logit Models with R" ([pdf](http://facweb.knowlton.ohio-state.edu/pviton/courses2/crp5700/5700-mlogit.pdf)):

> The specification of random parameters for the alternative-specific constants has changed from `mlogit` version 0.1-8.  The old version had `rpar=c(altair='n',altbus='n',alttrain='n')`. If you get an error here, try estimating model without random parameters (like model `res4` above), and note how the mode-specific dummys are reported; then use that syntax in the `rpar` argument.

Also see the 1st paragraph of p.26 of the documentation ([pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/mlogit.pdf)) about having to list the entire name of individual specific coefficients. I had a similar problem when trying to just use scan.id but it stated working when I started putting the `A:scan.id =` argument instead.  I believe you can do this with your data, as long as you set `panel=F` which I think is the only time the `id.var=scan.id` is invoked for multiple observation on the same person.  If you do in fact have a panel, then don't use that variable and use the other variables you want to simulate as normal or another distribution.  I'd also recommend using `halton=NA` argument if you have a large dataset as it speeds up the simulation significantly.

<sub>* Philip A. Viton (2014) *Discrete Choice Logit Models with R*.  Materials for Ohio State City and Regional Planning 5700.</sub>

Comment: Can you link to the documentation, or clarify your reference? I didn't see a footnote 20 on p 24 of the help pdf or either of the two vignettes.

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffacweb.knowlton.ohio-state.edu%2Fpviton%2Fcourses2%2Fcrp775%2F5700-mlogit.pdf%2F&ei=tctNVMr8FsKMyATE_4CICA&usg=AFQjCNHQp0z7aRmu-EnoVh89rygKp6xn8w&sig2=ReCyrh3dD7fsyXPGMRm3Iw&bvm=bv.77880786,d.aWw

Comment: Did you try my solution?  Did it work?

Comment: @gung did this solution work for you?

Comment: I didn't try it.

Comment: still no upvotes?  my answer solves the problem, check it out.